# Rails mobile-fu how to render html views for specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

In my rails application, I am using mobile-fu plugin to render mobile views. For specific controllers i need show the data in .html views in mobile broswers also. how to switch desktop views for specific controllers.

Rails Version 3.2.2

Answer (score 2):

added following lines to change format in specific controller

```
...
before_filter :clear_mobile_format


...
private
  def clear_mobile_format
    request.format = :html
  end
```